# React/Meteor: How to get data from component to its associated container?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I'm getting the data for my List component from a container. So far everything is fine.

There is an input field and a list of items (files). Right now there are thousands items and it doesn't make sense to show them all.
Thats why I would like to use a search field to get only matching items.

Typing a value to the input field will use `search()`, but now I need to get this value into the container element to get the specific data.

How do I get the value into the 'parent' container? Or maybe this kind of search has to be done completely different?

**/containers/list.js**

```
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data'
import List from '../components/List.jsx'

export default createContainer(() => {
  const subscription = Meteor.subscribe('files.all') // <-- better get specific data..., so use search term
  const files = Files.find().fetch()

  return { files }
}, List)
```

**/components/List.jsx**

```
export default class List extends Component {

  search (event, data) {
    const term = data.value
    console.log(term) // <-- term has to be used in the container...?
  }

  render () {
    const { files } = this.props

    const filesList = files.map((file, key) => {
      return (
        <ListFile
          key={'file' + key}
          file={file}
        />
      )
    }) || null

    return (
      <div id='list'>
        {
          filesList && 
          <div>
            <Input onChange={this.search.bind(this)}/>
            <Item.Group>
              { filesList }
            </Item.Group>
          </div>
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: @user3142695...Could you explain what this mean "filesList && 
          <div>
            <Input onChange={this.search.bind(this)}/>
            <Item.Group>
              { filesList }
            </Item.Group>
          </div>" ?

Comment: this will return some boolean or a div element because we are checking conditions here with and operator..

Answer (score 0):

Two options that I can think of:

1) Use Session (Meteor specific option).
2) Use Redux (Can be used in general).

Since you are using Meteor and it is out of the box there, I would advise to use Session.

In both parent and child import Session

import { Session } from "meteor/session";

In parent createContainer, do something like

```
const searchQuery = Session.get("searchQuery");

apply searchQuery in subscription or in Files.find() as you wish

return { files, searchQuery }
```

In child component, do something like

```
search (event, data) {
    const term = data.value
    console.log(term) 
    Session.set("searchQuery", term);
}
```